# Python Scipy library: saving images

Tags: python, image, scipy

I am learning image processing with scipy. I experience some diffuculties with rather basic opeartions as saving an image. Here is my code:

```
import scipy
from scipy import misc

img=misc.imread("C:\\..\\name.jpg")

misc.imsave("image.jpg",img)
```

I obtain error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    misc.imsave("image.jpg",img)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\misc\pilutil.py", line 158, in imsave
    im.save(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1461, in save
    fp = builtins.open(fp, "wb")
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'image.jpg'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the full path when saving:

```
misc.imsave(r'C:\path\image.jpg', img)
```

your error is a permission error, so probably you do not have access to write in the current directory. You can also change the current directory using `os.chdir( newpath )`.

Answer (score 0):

The code above creates a file in a given directory but it is empty (0 bytes) and produces error in the IDLE:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    misc.imsave(r"D:\Darek\back3.jpg", img)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\misc\pilutil.py", line 158, in imsave
    im.save(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1467, in save
    save_handler(self, fp, filename)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\JpegImagePlugin.py", line 557, in _save
    ImageFile._save(im, fp, [("jpeg", (0,0)+im.size, 0, rawmode)])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFile.py", line 466, in _save
    e = Image._getencoder(im.mode, e, a, im.encoderconfig)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 395, in _getencoder
    return encoder(mode, *args + extra)
TypeError: function takes at most 11 arguments (13 given)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, your code works fine for me in the dreampie shell

```
import scipy
from scipy import misc
img = misc.imread("C:/folder/name.jpg")
misc.imsave("C:/folder2/image.jpg",img)
```

I don't know PIL well enough, but there seems to be an encoder issue involved. Have you tried your code with different image files?

Comment: The same issue with other images. Maybe there is sth with the IDLE...
Same thing with IPython. :/